# BigInteger: count the number of decimal digits in a scalable method

Tags: java, biginteger

I need the count the number of decimal digits of a `BigInteger`. For example:

- `99` returns `2`
- `1234` returns `4`
- `9999` returns `4`
- `12345678901234567890` returns `20`

I need to do this *for a `BigInteger` with `184948` decimal digits and more*. **How can I do this fast and scalable?**

The *convert-to-String* approach is slow:

```
public String getWritableNumber(BigInteger number) {
   // Takes over 30 seconds for 184948 decimal digits
   return "10^" + (number.toString().length() - 1);
}
```

This *loop-devide-by-ten* approach is even slower:

```
public String getWritableNumber(BigInteger number) {
    int digitSize = 0;
    while (!number.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        number = number.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        digitSize++;
    }
    return "10^" + (digitSize - 1);
}
```

Are there any faster methods?

Comment: How slow is it and how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @Kayaman The faster of the 2 takes over 30 seconds for a number of 184948 decimal digits. I need it to be less than 2 seconds.

Comment: 2 seconds? That sounds a lot like the time limit of a programming competition.

Comment: There's some nice twiddles to do this - try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18054857/823393) to start with. May not apply to BigInteger.

Comment: @Dukeling No compo, I just don't want my JUnit tests to become so slow I won't run them before committing. The code is [here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/common/persistence/AbstractSolutionImporter.java#L96) if you're interested.

Comment: With [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), this is the one-liner `BigIntegerMath.log10(x, RoundingMode.FLOOR) + 1`.  Guava uses several of the tricks discussed here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like it is working. I haven't run exhaustive tests yet, n'or have I run any time tests but it seems to have a reasonable run time.

```
public class Test {
  /**
   * Optimised for huge numbers.
   *
   * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base
   *
   * States that log[b](x) = log[k](x)/log[k](b)
   *
   * We can get log[2](x) as the bitCount of the number so what we need is
   * essentially bitCount/log[2](10). Sadly that will lead to inaccuracies so
   * here I will attempt an iterative process that should achieve accuracy.
   *
   * log[2](10) = 3.32192809488736234787 so if I divide by 10^(bitCount/4) we
   * should not go too far. In fact repeating that process while adding (bitCount/4)
   * to the running count of the digits will end up with an accurate figure
   * given some twiddling at the end.
   * 
   * So here's the scheme:
   * 
   * While there are more than 4 bits in the number
   *   Divide by 10^(bits/4)
   *   Increase digit count by (bits/4)
   * 
   * Fiddle around to accommodate the remaining digit - if there is one.
   * 
   * Essentially - each time around the loop we remove a number of decimal 
   * digits (by dividing by 10^n) keeping a count of how many we've removed.
   * 
   * The number of digits we remove is estimated from the number of bits in the 
   * number (i.e. log[2](x) / 4). The perfect figure for the reduction would be
   * log[2](x) / 3.3219... so dividing by 4 is a good under-estimate. We 
   * don't go too far but it does mean we have to repeat it just a few times.
   */
  private int log10(BigInteger huge) {
    int digits = 0;
    int bits = huge.bitLength();
    // Serious reductions.
    while (bits > 4) {
      // 4 > log[2](10) so we should not reduce it too far.
      int reduce = bits / 4;
      // Divide by 10^reduce
      huge = huge.divide(BigInteger.TEN.pow(reduce));
      // Removed that many decimal digits.
      digits += reduce;
      // Recalculate bitLength
      bits = huge.bitLength();
    }
    // Now 4 bits or less - add 1 if necessary.
    if ( huge.intValue() > 9 ) {
      digits += 1;
    }
    return digits;
  }

  // Random tests.
  Random rnd = new Random();
  // Limit the bit length.
  int maxBits = BigInteger.TEN.pow(200000).bitLength();

  public void test() {
    // 100 tests.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      BigInteger huge = new BigInteger((int)(Math.random() * maxBits), rnd);
      // Note start time.
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      // Do my method.
      int myLength = log10(huge);
      // Record my result.
      System.out.println("Digits: " + myLength+ " Took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
      // Check the result.
      int trueLength = huge.toString().length() - 1;
      if (trueLength != myLength) {
        System.out.println("WRONG!! " + (myLength - trueLength));
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }

}
```

Took about 3 seconds on my Celeron M laptop so it should hit sub 2 seconds on some decent kit.

Comment: Takes about 0.35 seconds on my 64bit i7 for numbers of the order of 10^180000

Comment: I found a mistake in the code while testing - I was using bitCount instead of bitLength - please refresh your copy if you took one. Now takes about 0.22 seconds for your huge numbers.

Comment: If you want a faster algorithm, take a look at what BigDecimal uses to calculate the length of its mantissa :-)

Answer (score 16):

Here's a fast method based on [Dariusz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18828536/319821):

```
public static int getDigitCount(BigInteger number) {
  double factor = Math.log(2) / Math.log(10);
  int digitCount = (int) (factor * number.bitLength() + 1);
  if (BigInteger.TEN.pow(digitCount - 1).compareTo(number) > 0) {
    return digitCount - 1;
  }
  return digitCount;
}
```

The following code tests the numbers 1, 9, 10, 99, 100, 999, 1000, etc. all the way to ten-thousand digits:

```
public static void test() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.TEN.pow(i);
    if (getDigitCount(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) != i || getDigitCount(n) != i + 1) {
      System.out.println("Failure: " + i);
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Done");
}
```

This can check a *`BigInteger`* with *`184,948`* decimal digits and more in well under a second.

Comment: would just add some small changes as for ZERO you'll get 0 instead of 1 and for negative values the number of digits are little bit of (so you need to negate the number first). But otherwise good job (you and Dariusz) (gave you both a +1)

Answer (score 9):

I think that you could use [bitLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength%28%29) to get a log2 value, then [change the base to 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).

The result may be wrong, however, by one digit, so this is just an approximation.

However, if that's acceptable, you could always add 1 to the result and bound it to be *at most*. Or, subtract 1, and get *at least*.

Comment: It may be possible to combine this with `testBit` in a loop to get an exact answer, although it would be slow for some cases.

Comment: @Dukeling I can't think of how to do it without calculating the original number. You can test few last bits, but you'd deal in probabilities anyway.

Comment: Well, if you have 16 bits, the range is 65536 (5 digits) - 131071 (6 digits). If you were to check the first 3 bits and you get `111`, this would guarantee 6 digits, similarly `10` guarantees 5 digits. So you can really just keep checking from the left until you get into some range containing a fixed number of digits.

Comment: Doing BigInteger.pow() is relatively fast (less than 1 second for 184948 decimal digits IIRC). So maybe `10.pow(result)` can be used to resolve the *off by 1 digit* problem

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert the `BigInteger` to a `BigDecimal` and then use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21443880/2585059) to compute the number of digits. This seems more efficient than using `BigInteger.toString()` as that would allocate memory for `String` representation.

```
    private static int numberOfDigits(BigInteger value) {
        return significantDigits(new BigDecimal(value));
    }

    private static int significantDigits(BigDecimal value) {
        return value.scale() < 0
               ? value.precision() - value.scale()
               : value.precision();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an another way to do it faster than Convert-to-String method. Not the best run time, but still reasonable 0.65 seconds versus 2.46 seconds with Convert-to-String method (at 180000 digits).

This method computes the integer part of the base-10 logarithm from the given value. However, instead of using loop-divide, it uses a technique similar to Exponentiation by Squaring.

Here is a crude implementation that achieves the runtime mentioned earlier:

```
public static BigInteger log(BigInteger base,BigInteger num)
{
    /* The technique tries to get the products among the squares of base
     * close to the actual value as much as possible without exceeding it.
     * */
    BigInteger resultSet = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger actMult = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger lastMult = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger actor = base;
    BigInteger incrementor = BigInteger.ONE;
    while(actMult.multiply(base).compareTo(num)<1)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while(actMult.multiply(actor).compareTo(num)<1)
        {
            lastMult = actor; //Keep the old squares
            actor = actor.multiply(actor); //Square the base repeatedly until the value exceeds 
            if(count>0) incrementor = incrementor.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            //Update the current exponent of the base
            count++;
        }
        if(count == 0) break;

        /* If there is no way to multiply the "actMult"
         * with squares of the base (including the base itself)
         * without keeping it below the actual value, 
         * it is the end of the computation 
         */
        actMult = actMult.multiply(lastMult);
        resultSet = resultSet.add(incrementor);
        /* Update the product and the exponent
         * */
        actor = base;
        incrementor = BigInteger.ONE;
        //Reset the values for another iteration
    }
    return resultSet;
}
public static int digits(BigInteger num)
{
    if(num.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) return 1;
    if(num.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)<0) num = num.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(-1));
    return log(BigInteger.valueOf(10),num).intValue()+1;
}
```

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record; I can answer in JS but should be the same in any reasonable language.

Obviously you can convert it into a string and check the length but that's... what can i say... UGLY.

- If it is not a `BigInt` (say less than 16 digits) Than
  `Math.floor(Math.log10(number))` should do it.
- If it's a `BigInt` then you can always divide it `n` times by `1e16` up until it's remainder is less than `1e16`. Then the number of digits is

`n * 16 + Math.floor(Math.log10(remainder))`