# Neat way to find the number of significant digits in a BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, significant-digits

I do not want to limit the number of significant digits in a BigDecimal. I only want to find the number of significant digits that number has.

Is there a way to do this without converting the number to string and count the number characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want a combination of [`stripTrailingZeros`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29), [`precision`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#precision%28%29) and [`scale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale%28%29), as demonstrated here:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("5000");      // 4
        test("5000.00");   // 4
        test("5000.12");   // 6
        test("35000");     // 5
        test("35000.00");  // 5
        test("35000.12");  // 7
        test("35000.120"); // 7
        test("0.0034");    // 2
        test("1.0034");    // 5
        test("1.00340");   // 5
    }


    private static void test(String input) {
        System.out.println(input + " => " +
            significantDigits(new BigDecimal(input)));
    }

    private static int significantDigits(BigDecimal input) {
        input = input.stripTrailingZeros();
        return input.scale() < 0
            ? input.precision() - input.scale()
            : input.precision(); 
    }
}
```

The call to `stripTrailingZeros` is required as otherwise it's entirely possible for a `BigDecimal` to be stored in a "non-normalized" form. For example, `new BigDecimal(5000)` has a precision of 4, not 1.

The call to `scale()` is used to handle cases where the normalized form has trailing zeroes *before* the decimal point, but nothing *after* the decimal point. In this case, the scale will always be negative, and indicates the number of trailing zeroes.

EDIT: Cases with trailing zeroes but no decimal point are inherently ambiguous - there's no definite number of significant digits to "5000" for example. The above code treats all trailing zeroes before the decimal point as significant.

Comment: You're right in that `precision()` alone isn't the answer, but `new BigDecimal(8.6).precision()` somehow returns `50`, and `new BigDecimal(8.6).stripTrailingZeroes().precision()` also returns `50`.

Comment: @rgettman: That's because `new BigDecimal(8.6)` isn't actually 8.6... it's the exact value of the nearest `double` to `8.6`. If you expected to get 2, you should use `new BigDecimal("8.6")`. Just print out `new BigDecimal(8.6)` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: The other problem is that `new BigDecimal("5000.0").stripTrailingZeros().precision()` returns 1, but according to the accepted definitions you want it to return 5 (since you wouldn't add `.0` to the end of a number unless it were significant).  Also, the number of significant digits in `"5000"` is ambiguous anyway.  See "Significant figures" in Wikipedia.

Comment: @ajb: Ah, nice catch. I had *expected* a value of 1 there, thinking about it more in scientific terms (where 5000 = 5x10^3).

Comment: @Jon Actually, I tried to limit the number of significant digits so that it would fit into Decimal(3,2) in mysql database. But it appears that even though I enter 300, the data is out of range. Any suggestion?

Comment: @abcXYZ: It's not clear what you mean by that, I'm afraid - but it seems to be outside the realm of this question. If you're interested in MySQL, I'd ask a question *about MySQL*.

Comment: @ajb: See my edit - do you think that fixes it? (I *think* it does, but I'd welcome a second opinion.)

Comment: @abcXYZ: I'm not sure what you mean. You haven't really told us what you're trying to achieve - and as I say, this question was only about BigDecimal. Ask a new question about MySQL...

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the correct answers for your test cases should be 1(?), 6, 6, 2(?), 7, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6.  (The ? cases are ambiguous, and `BigDecimal` isn't capable of distinguishing between, say, a "5000" with one significant digit and a "5000" with two, for example.)

Comment: @ajb: Yes, this treats the ambiguity as "all digits before the decimal point are significant". I suspect that's as good as it's likely to get :(

Answer (score 1):

The following modification of Jon's answer returns the results that seem correct to me:

```
private static int significantDigits(BigDecimal input) {
    return input.scale() <= 0
        ? input.precision() + input.stripTrailingZeros().scale()
        : input.precision();
}
```

(Note that `input.stripTrailingZeros().scale()` appears to always be negative in these tests.)

Also, as I noted above, `BigDecimal` isn't capable of distinguishing between, say, a "5000" with one significant digit and a "5000" with two, for example.  Furthermore, according to the definitions, "5000." (with a trailing decimal point) should have exactly four significant digits, but `BigDecimal` isn't capable of handling that.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures for the definitions I'm using.)

Answer (score 0):

Jon's answer is correct in most cases except exponential number:

```
private static int significantDigits(BigDecimal input) {
return input.scale() <= 0
    ? input.precision() + input.stripTrailingZeros().scale()
    : input.precision();
}
```

let's say the input as 1.230000E17, the function returns 18 however the correct significant digits should be 7.