# Binary logarithm without java.lang.Math?

Tags: java, math, logarithm

How is it possible to perform a binary logarithm without using `Math`?
Now I have this `Math.log(x) / Math.log(2)` and it works but I can't use `java.lang.Math`.

What can I do?

```
int bits_necessaris = (int)(log2(nat + 1)); // This is correct

// The function where I'm having trouble

public static int log2(int x) {
    return (something);
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** When I performed `Math.log(7) / Math.log(2)` I got `2.80XXXXX`

So I did this:

```
(int) Math.ceil(Math.log(7) / Math.log(2));
```

And I get `ceil(2.80XXXXX) = 3`.

The return of the function has to be rounded up, for example if the solution is 6.777 the return has to be 7.

Comment: So by "Math" you mean the class Math? Can you copy the source of Math and put it in an other class with a different name?

Comment: Note that the log-base-2 of a number is approximately the number of significant bits in the number.

Comment: Yes, the class to do SQUAREROOT POW LOG etc.. I can't create another class, I must use the function that I wrote above

Comment: Make x positive and then perform binary search with x<(1<<k) for k between 0 and 30. If x>=(1<<30) then you need 31bit plus the sign bit.

Comment: I don't know how binary search works, nobody taught me that so I asume that I don't need to use this method

Comment: You can right shift the input number (note: using `>>>`) until it gets to 0, all the while incrementing an integer starting at 0.

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18860385/823393) trick. It uses `BigInteger.TEN.pow` but that's nearly not `Math`.

Comment: Why is everybody answering in the comments? You won't get upvotes that way ;-)

Comment: @meriton - Upvotes are uncool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know how many bits are necessary to represent an int? Then there are easier solutions such as:

```java
int bitsNeededFor(int i) {
    int bits = 0;
    while (i > 0) {
        bits++;
        i /= 2;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

On second thought, the following is faster and easier to understand:

```java
int bitsNeededFor(int i) {
    return 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked fine, I was too much focused on using logarithm

Comment: I think this won't work for powers of two, e.g. 2³=8=1000 will return 4.

Comment: It correctly computes the number of bits needed (i.e. 1 + floor(log2(i))), which is what OP is ultimately after.