# What is the fastest way to split Integer into digits?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections

I do a lot of operations with splitting numbers into separate digits, putting digits in ArrayList and passing this digits one by one to other ArrayList for further operations until tempList is empty - then goes the next number which is bigger than previous.

I'd like to know which approach is faster.

The part that is common to both approaches:

```
// Split number into digits and put into array
BigInteger number; // the number can be very big => BigInteger
ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
while (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1) {
   tempList.add((number.mod(BigInteger.TEN)).intValue());
   number = number.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
}
```

Then I can go 2 ways passing those digits to other ArrayList mainList one by one and deleting them after:
Way 1:

```
// reverse the tempList (as digits are put there backwards) and take the first elements
Collections.reverse(tempList);
while (!tempList.isEmpty()) {
    mainList.add(tempList.get(0);
    tempList.remove(0);
}
```

Way 2:

```
// take the last elements
while (!tempList.isEmpty()) {
    mainList.add(tempList.get(tempList.size()-1);
    tempList.remove(tempList.get(tempList.size()-1);
}
```

Which way is faster? Taking into consideration, that it's billions of operations with billions of numbers being split and added. I supposed that method such as Collections.reverse() takes more time, but I only call it every time tempList is updated with new digits from next number. But in Way 2 I call .size()-1 operation on EVERY operation.

Also the bigger the number - the bigger the gap between updating the tempList and taking numbers from it (obviously), so less .reverse() method calling.
The number starts at 1 and goes to infinity.

tempList is there for a reason, so please, do not suggest to bypass it.

Additional question: what is the best practice of measuring such things?

Comment: Moving from one list to another is useless.

Comment: @Roman C. Why? That is only part of the code, the tempList is there for a reason.

Comment: In your code you declare `tempList` but then refer to a `list` variable. Are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: @davmac Thank you, that's a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caution. There are some gotchas involved here.

In fact, there are two questions mixed:

- How to transfer data from one list to another, in reverse order?
- How to create a list of digits from a `BigInteger`?

I agree with the [comment by Roman C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186193/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-split-integer-into-digits#comment54178355_33186193): *"Moving from one list to another is useless"*. At least, it seems to be useless in this case. But if there is something happening to the `tempList`, and the general approach of removing elements from one list and adding them to another list (one by one) is justified in any way, then the question of how to improve the performance for this particular case may still be feasible.

---

Regarding the core question of how to transfer data from one list to another, in reverse order:

Surprisingly, in the form that it is written now,

**...the second snippet is *far* slower than the first one!**

(Explanation follows)

A simple test like this one compares both approaches. (Of course, "micorbenchmarks" like this one should be taken with a grain of salt, but as the performance here is related to asymptotic running times, this is reasonable here)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

public class BigIntegerDigitsPerformanceLists
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testListConversion();
    }

    private static void testListConversion()
    {
        long before = 0;
        long after = 0;

        for (int size = 10; size <= 1000000; size *= 10)
        {
            List<Integer> inputA = createRandomList(size);
            List<Integer> inputB = createRandomList(size);

            before = System.nanoTime();
            List<Integer> resultA = convertA(inputA);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH,
                "A: size %8d time %8.2fms result %d\n",
                size, (after-before)/1e6, resultA.get(0));

            before = System.nanoTime();
            List<Integer> resultB = convertB(inputB);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH,
                "B: size %8d time %8.2fms result %d\n",
                size, (after-before)/1e6, resultB.get(0));
        }
    }

    private static List<Integer> createRandomList(int size)
    {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random(0);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            result.add(random.nextInt(10));
        }
        return result;
    }


    private static List<Integer> convertA(List<Integer> list)
    {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Collections.reverse(list);
        while (!list.isEmpty())
        {
            result.add(list.get(0));
            list.remove(0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> convertB(List<Integer> list)
    {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (!list.isEmpty())
        {
            result.add(list.get(list.size() - 1));
            list.remove(list.get(list.size() - 1));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The output on my machine is

```
A: size       10 time     0.08ms result 4
B: size       10 time     0.05ms result 4
A: size      100 time     0.13ms result 1
B: size      100 time     0.39ms result 1
A: size     1000 time     1.27ms result 6
B: size     1000 time     2.96ms result 6
A: size    10000 time    39.72ms result 1
B: size    10000 time   220.82ms result 1
A: size   100000 time  3766.45ms result 7
B: size   100000 time 21734.66ms result 7
...
```

### But....

This is due to a wrong method call. The second approach contains the line

```
list.remove(list.get(list.size() - 1));
```

and this is the culprit in this case: You have a list of `Integer` objects. And you are calling `remove`, passing in an `Integer` object. This method will search through the whole list, and remove the first  occurrence of the argument. This is not only slow, it also causes the result to be plainly wrong!

What you actually want to do is to remove the last element, using the **index** of the last element. So changing this line to

```
list.remove((int)list.size() - 1);
```

gives an entirely different timing result:

```
A: size       10 time     0.08ms result 4
B: size       10 time     0.03ms result 4
A: size      100 time     0.13ms result 1
B: size      100 time     0.10ms result 1
A: size     1000 time     1.28ms result 6
B: size     1000 time     0.46ms result 6
A: size    10000 time    39.09ms result 1
B: size    10000 time     2.63ms result 1
A: size   100000 time  3763.97ms result 7
B: size   100000 time     9.83ms result 7
...
```

So, when implemented properly, then

**...the first snippet is *far* slower than the second one!**

For the reasons that [Eran mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186253/3182664).

---

Regarding the question of how to create a list of digits from a `BigInteger`: There are several possible performance improvements.

Extracting the digits manually, with a sequence of `%= 10` and `/= 10` calls is very slow. Avoiding the modulo operation already brings a small speedup. So instead of

```
digit = number % 10;
number = number / 10;
```

you could do

```
nextNumber = number / 10;
digit = number - (nextNumber * 10);
number = nextNumber;
```

But due to the immutability of `BigInteger` and the expensive division, this is still orders of magnitude slower than simply converting the `BigInteger` into a string, and extracting the digits from there, as [dasblinkenlight suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186333/3182664).

A simple comparison:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

public class BigIntegerDigitsPerformance
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testListCreation();
    }

    private static void testListCreation()
    {
        long before = 0;
        long after = 0;

        for (int size = 10; size <= 100000; size *= 10)
        {
            BigInteger number = createRandomBigInteger(size);

            before = System.nanoTime();
            List<Integer> resultA = createA(number);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH,
                "A: size %8d time %8.2fms result %d\n",
                size, (after-before)/1e6, resultA.get(0));

            before = System.nanoTime();
            List<Integer> resultB = createB(number);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH,
                "B: size %8d time %8.2fms result %d\n",
                size, (after-before)/1e6, resultB.get(0));

            before = System.nanoTime();
            List<Integer> resultC = createC(number);
            after = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH,
                "B: size %8d time %8.2fms result %d\n",
                size, (after-before)/1e6, resultC.get(0));
        }
    }


    private static BigInteger createRandomBigInteger(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random(0);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(random.nextInt(10)));
        }
        return new BigInteger(sb.toString());
    }


    private static List<Integer> createA(BigInteger number)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1)
        {
            list.add((number.mod(BigInteger.TEN)).intValue());
            number = number.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static List<Integer> createB(BigInteger number)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1)
        {
            BigInteger next = number.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
            BigInteger diff = number.subtract(next.multiply(BigInteger.TEN));
            list.add(diff.intValue());
            number = next;
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static List<Integer> createC(BigInteger number)
    {
        String s = number.toString();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(s.length());
        for (int i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            list.add(s.charAt(i) - '0');
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The output will be along the lines of this:

```
...
A: size     1000 time     9.20ms result 6
B: size     1000 time     6.44ms result 6
C: size     1000 time     1.96ms result 6
A: size    10000 time   452.44ms result 1
B: size    10000 time   334.82ms result 1
C: size    10000 time    16.29ms result 1
A: size   100000 time 43876.93ms result 7
B: size   100000 time 32334.84ms result 7
C: size   100000 time   297.92ms result 7
```

showing that the `toString` approach is more than a hundred times faster than the manual ones.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed review if the issue. I appreciate it a lot. And especially for pointing at my mistake with.  `bank.remove(bank.get((bank.size() - 1)));`
That came from the line above where i take the digit to pass it to another list. `arrayS.add(bank.get(bank.size() - 1));` I just automatically repeated the line and changed add with remove. Should be more careful.

Comment: as i understand from your code, `s.charAt(i) - '0'` is a tricky faster way of conversion char into Integer then Character.getNumericValue()?

Comment: Admittedly, I did not even know `Character.getNumericValue`. It seems to involve some special unicode treatments. In any case, for plain ASCII strings, the character `'0'` has the `int` value 48. So subtracting `'0'` from a `char` like `'0' ... '9'` gives exactly the corresponding value (as an `int`) that is denoted by the character, namely `0 ... 9`

Answer (score 3):

The second snippet should be faster for two reasons :

1. Not having to reverse the ArrayList, as you recognized yourself.
2. Removing the last element of an ArrayList is faster than removing the first element, since removing the first element involves decreasing the index of all the remaining elements (which is done via System.arraycopy).

Answer (score 2):

Both snippets are slow. If you want to do it faster, make a list of the proper size, and fill it in from the back.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773083/335858) shows how to obtain the length of the required `ArrayList<Integer>`. Now you can do this:

```
BigInteger number; // the number can be very big => BigInteger
ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>(
    // getDigitCount comes from the answer linked above
    Collections.nCopies(getDigitCount(number), 0)
);
int pos = res.size()-1;
while (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1) {
    res.set(pos--, (number.mod(BigInteger.TEN)).intValue());
    number = number.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
}
```

This produces `ArrayList` in the desired order right away, so the reversing routines become completely unnecessary.

Note: Java-8 lets you do the conversion to an array of integer in one line:

```
BigInteger number = new BigInteger("12345678910111213141516171819");
List<Integer> res = number
    .toString()
    .chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> Character.digit(c, 10))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/xjPLdu)

Comment: Thank you. I suppose there is a typo in your code. You use `res` and then switch to `list` when filling it. Anyway this is useful, but still, how is this faster then way 2? For every number i create new ArrayList instead of using the existing one, fill it and then have to take numbers (elements) from the 0 position, thus causing an issue 2. of @Eran answer.

Comment: @Emptyfruit You have `tempList` that you create for every number, no?

Comment: No, it is constant (contrary to its name). It is cleared out element by element and then filled fully with the next number. Sorry, i see that it is not clear from my code sample.

Comment: sorry i can't try your demo, as i'm on Java 7. Even if i was to create new array every time, isn't taking the first element is slower then taking the last?

Comment: @Emptyfruit You don't have to create the list every time in my solution as well, as long as you can expand/shrink the array instead. Taking any element from an `ArrayList` takes the same constant time, it's deleting that is done at different speeds.

Comment: You're right of course, it's just in case of this code by taking i mean get() and remove() pair. Thank you for your help.