# How to specify length of id in Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

How I can specify the length constraint of 'ID' from 15-25 symbols in my spring boot rest application using Redis?

```
@RedisHash("Foo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Indexed
  private Status status;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to change `id` type to `String` and set `Size` for symbols length limitations but it doesn't work(it seems `Size` annotation ignored) in the scope of Redis db usage:

```
@RedisHash("Foo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Size(min = 15, max = 25)
  private String id;

  @Indexed
  private Status status;
}
```

I have also tried to use custom validator also and the same behaviour - seems like it`s ignored when Redis db is used:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = DigitsLimitValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DigitsLimit {

  String message() default "Digits length is too short or long";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

  int min() default 5;

  int max() default 15;

}
```

Validator:

```
public class DigitsLimitValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DigitsLimit, BigInteger> {

  private int min;
  private int max;

    @Override
    public void initialize(DigitsLimit value) {
      min = value.min();
      max = value.max();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(BigInteger value, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
      return value != null && BigIntegerMath.log10(value, RoundingMode.FLOOR) + 1 >= min && BigIntegerMath.log10(value, RoundingMode.FLOOR) + 1 <= max;
    }

  }
```

Model:

```
@RedisHash("Foo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @DigitsLimit(min = 15, max = 25)
  private BigInteger id;

  @Indexed
  private Status status;
}
```

Under debugging mode, I cannot catch any breakpoints inside my validator.

In both attempts I can save any length of digits. Limitations are ignored. Why it was ignored?

Answer (score 0):

> How I can specify the length constraint of 'ID' from 15-25 symbols

It makes no sense to use the `Long` type as `Long.MAX_VALUE` has "only" 19 digits.

> 9223372036854775807

To contain such a value, `BigInteger` is probably a better choice.

You could not add the `@Min` and `@Max`  annotations to a `BigInteger` field as the values are limited to the `Long` range. So you could not represent 25 digits.

So you have two ways :

- creating [a custom validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator) that ensures that your constraint is respected.
- replacing the numeric value by a `String`. You could so use the `javax.validation.constraints.Size` annotation that is not applicable to numeric fields but is for `CharSequence` fields such as `String`.

For example :

```
@Id
@Size(min=15, max=25)
private String id;
```

Comment: Thanks! But how I can limit BigInteger in the case of 15-25 symbols?

Comment: I would like to generate id with 15 symbols and the max allowed symbols is 25

Comment: You are welcome. It could not work with `BigInteger`. I edited with two ways.

Comment: Ou, thanks. If I choose custom validator based on BigInteger field how I can count number of digits in the field? Maybe there is more elegant way to count digits of BigInteger value beside the solution which I have found - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828377/biginteger-count-the-number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-scalable-method/18828536#18828536